# React Dropdown Selection - Increment or Decrement based on arrow button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a dropdown input. I want to move the currently selected option forward or backward when a left or right arrow button is clicked next to the input. It should also keep track of the option when the dropdown itself is clicked and an option is selected.

I am able to capture the value of the currently selected object when clicked with e.target.value (and console log), and I am able to increment or decrement the count on the state when the arrow buttons are clicked (and console log), but I am unsure of the best way to tie the two together (show the item at the "count" position index in the array?)

Here is my code:

```
class DropdownMenu extends Component {
  state = {
    // Select options
    options: [
      { name: 'Item 1', label: 'Item 1' },
      { name: 'Item 2', label: 'Item 2' },
      { name: 'Item 3', label: 'Item 3' },
      { name: 'Item 4', label: 'Item 4' },
      { name: 'Item 5', label: 'Item 5' }
    ],
    value: 'select', // this should be the initial item ('Item 1')
    count: 0
  };

  change = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value }, console.log(this.state));
  };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        count: this.state.count + 1
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        count: this.state.count - 1
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };

  // Here I map over the options in state

  dropdown = () => (
    <div className="dropdown position-relative">
      <select onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
        {this.state.options.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={index} name={option.name} value={option.name}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <div className="descend">
        <img className="icon" src={descendIcon} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  // I want to use these arrows to increment or decrement the selection on the drop down

  leftArrow = icon => (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-2"
      onClick={this.handleIncrement}
    >
      <img className="icon" src={icon} alt="left arrow" />
    </button>
  );

  rightArrow = icon => (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-2"
      onClick={this.handleDecrement}
    >
      <img className="icon" src={icon} alt="" />
    </button>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className="flex-grow">{this.dropdown()}</div>
        <div>
          {this.leftArrow(leftIcon)}
          {this.rightArrow(rightIcon)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropdownMenu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `this.state.count` stores the selected `options` index. If we  set `this.state.count` as the `select` menu's `value` then when the state updates the `select` will re-render and display the option that matches the updated count.

Live Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/38v727rrm

```
class DropdownMenu extends React.Component {
    state = {
        // Select options
        options: [
            { name: 'Item 1', label: 'Item 1' },
            { name: 'Item 2', label: 'Item 2' },
            { name: 'Item 3', label: 'Item 3' },
            { name: 'Item 4', label: 'Item 4' },
            { name: 'Item 5', label: 'Item 5' }
        ],
        count: 0
    };
    change = e => {
        this.setState({ count: Number(e.target.value) });
    };
    handleIncrement = () => {
        const c = this.state.count;
        const len = this.state.options.length - 1;
        let count = (c + 1 > len) ? c : c + 1;
        this.setState({ count });
    };
    handleDecrement = () => {
        const c = this.state.count;
        let count = (c - 1 < 0) ? c : c - 1;
        this.setState({ count });
    };
    dropdown = () => (
        <div className="dropdown position-relative">
            <select onChange={this.change} value={this.state.count}>
                {this.state.options.map((option, index) => (
                    <option key={index} name={option.name} value={index}>
                        {option.label}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <div className="descend">
                <img className="icon" src="" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    leftArrow = icon => (
        <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-2"
            onClick={this.handleDecrement}
            >
            <img className="icon" src={icon} alt="left arrow" />
        </button>
    );
    rightArrow = icon => (
        <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-2"
            onClick={this.handleIncrement}
            >
            <img className="icon" src={icon} alt="right arrow" />
        </button>
    );    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="flex flex-row">
                <div className="flex-grow">{this.dropdown()}</div>
                <div>
                    {this.leftArrow('leftIcon')}
                    {this.rightArrow('rightIcon')}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store both `count` and `value` in your state, since you'd then have two sources of truth for what should be selected. Just store `count`, and anywhere that you'd get `value`, get `options[count]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I miss interpreted your question, so you can do that using the logic described by joseph.
Use options[index] to get value, and always update the index

Look: https://codesandbox.io/s/zpwvjxjol

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [React recommended way to handle setState](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/react-docs-now-recommends-using-function-with-prevstate-inside-of-setstate).

Since React can batch setState calls for better performance you just can't rely purely on this.state.count to use it as starting point to update your state. Instead, you need to call setState passing prevState as one of the parameters and use the prevState.count + 1